# image_picker is not working after building flutter apps for Camera Image Picking

Tags: flutter-image-picker

```
_getFromCamera() async {
  XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
  );
}
```

It is working fine for

```
source: ImageSource.gallery,
```

but for camera, it is not working

I have tried at first flutter version upgrading, installing

```
permission_handler
```

package but not working after building the apps

Answer (score 0):

At first, need to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

After that, install permission_handler package.

Then the build will work for both camera and gallery. It will ask for permission and works fine.